# Aviary ios SDK memory not released after dismiss

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, aviary

I am using Aviary SDK 3.0 in my app, I put the Aviary code in a popover like this, but after I dismissed the popover using [popover dismissPopoverAnimated], the Aviary is still in the memory Heap, this is even true, even after I dismissed the parent viewcontroller. is it expected that the Aviary code is cleaned up after I dismiss?

in the action when use tap the photo. I present it here

```
    AFPhotoEditorController *editorController = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:imageToEdit];
    [editorController setDelegate:self];

    if (popover == nil)
        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:editorController];
    else
        [popover setContentViewController:editorController animated:YES];
```

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23238574/Screenshots/aviarypopover.png[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

"Note that pushing the controller onto a UINavigationController's stack is not recommended, since the Photo Editor itself uses a subclass of UINavigationController."

try presenting it modally, then what I do just to make me feel better about all memory getting cleaned is to make a strong property and go through the checklist

```
[editorController removeFromParentViewController];
editorController.delegate = nil;
editorController = nil;
```

something about clearing the delegate seems to clear my memory better, although, I don't think you need it.

also, don't forget:

"By default, Aviary keeps a small number of OpenGL objects loaded to optimize launches of Aviary products."

```
[AFOpenGLManager requestOpenGLDataPurge];
// to request a clear, 
// "Calls to requestOpenGLDataPurge only apply to the currently loaded OpenGL data,"
```

You can set it to clear regularly with

```
[AFPhotoEditorCustomization purgeGPUMemoryWhenPossible:YES];
```

if you're doing this, it's a good idea to preload some of the editor if you know they'll be using it soon

```
[AFOpenGLManager beginOpenGLLoad];
```

Answer (score 0):

This memory leak has been addressed in subsequent releases of the SDK. Please visit [developers.aviary.com](http://developers.aviary.com) to get the latest version.